# How to add a plone.registry record programatically

Tags: plone

I'm writing an upgrade step that adds a record to a registry that will be used on a control panel configlet.

I started by adding a profile with a **registry.xml** file on it but then I though there should be a way to accomplish this programatically to avoid the creation and registration of a GS profile just for this.

I read the documentation of [plone.registtry](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.registry) and according to it, the **value_type** properties of **List** may only contain persistent fields, so I came out with this code:

```py
from collective.cover import _
from collective.cover.config import DEFAULT_AVAILABLE_TILES
from collective.cover.config import PROJECTNAME
from plone.registry import field
from plone.registry import Record
from plone.registry.interfaces import IRegistry
from zope.component import getUtility

import logging


def register_available_tiles_record(context, logger=None):
    """Handler for upgrade step from 2 to 3; adds the 'available_tiles' record
    to the registry.
    """
    if logger is None:
        logger = logging.getLogger(PROJECTNAME)

    registry = getUtility(IRegistry)
    record = 'collective.cover.controlpanel.ICoverSettings.available_tiles'

    if record not in registry.records:
        available_tiles = field.List(
            title=_(u"Available tiles"),
            description=_(u"This tiles will be available for layout creation."),
            required=True,
            default=DEFAULT_AVAILABLE_TILES,
            value_type=field.Choice(
                vocabulary=u'collective.cover.EnabledTiles'),
        )

        registry.records[record] = Record(available_tiles)
        logger.info("'available_tiles' record was added to the registry")
    else:
        logger.info("'available_tiles' record already exists in the registry")
```

but when I run the handler, I'm getting the following error:

```py
Error in test test_from_2_to_3 (collective.cover.tests.test_upgrades.UpgradeStepsTestCase)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hvelarde/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 327, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/home/hvelarde/collective/cover/src/collective/cover/tests/test_upgrades.py", line 35, in test_from_2_to_3
    register_available_tiles_record(self.portal)
  File "/home/hvelarde/collective/cover/src/collective/cover/upgrades.py", line 31, in register_available_tiles_record
    vocabulary=u'collective.cover.EnabledTiles'),
  File "/home/hvelarde/.buildout/eggs/zope.schema-4.2.2-py2.7.egg/zope/schema/_field.py", line 458, in __init__
    super(AbstractCollection, self).__init__(**kw)
  File "/home/hvelarde/.buildout/eggs/zope.schema-4.2.2-py2.7.egg/zope/schema/_bootstrapfields.py", line 306, in __init__
    super(MinMaxLen, self).__init__(**kw)
  File "/home/hvelarde/.buildout/eggs/zope.schema-4.2.2-py2.7.egg/zope/schema/_bootstrapfields.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.default = default
  File "/home/hvelarde/.buildout/eggs/zope.schema-4.2.2-py2.7.egg/zope/schema/_bootstrapfields.py", line 53, in __set__
    inst.validate(value)
  File "/home/hvelarde/.buildout/eggs/zope.schema-4.2.2-py2.7.egg/zope/schema/_bootstrapfields.py", line 182, in validate
    self._validate(value)
  File "/home/hvelarde/.buildout/eggs/zope.schema-4.2.2-py2.7.egg/zope/schema/_field.py", line 476, in _validate
    errors = _validate_sequence(self.value_type, value)
  File "/home/hvelarde/.buildout/eggs/zope.schema-4.2.2-py2.7.egg/zope/schema/_field.py", line 438, in _validate_sequence
    value_type.validate(item)
AttributeError: 'InterfaceConstrainedProperty' object has no attribute 'validate'
```

what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: code for this is here: https://github.com/collective/collective.cover/commit/898b22bf26ac914322103d0d94690c3427296174

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems to me this is a limitation/bug of plone.registry; I ended up with a normal registry registration on the upgrade step.

anybody interested can see it here: https://github.com/collective/collective.cover/commit/137211a84a575fc03fbb84e0cbd091bec85a6ab7